# Is it possible to get the last number of a views pager to display after and before the elipses?

Tags: 7, views, theming, paging

I'm trying to create a custom pager similar to the Amazon pager:

> < 1 2 3 4 ... **82** >

and after a certain point:

> < **1** ... 7 8 9 10 ... **82** >

But, I cant figure out how to display the last pager number after the elipse. Is this possible? What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: A simple google search reveals a lot of solutions on this topic. Try "drupal views theme pager".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it's been working for me.

First I set the pager items to display as inline-block. Then I styled the .prev/.next items to float left/right respectively so they're on the outside.

I used `hook_preprocess_pager` and `$pager_total` to set the last pager number `$variables['tags'][4]`.

```
function hook_preprocess_pager(&$variables, $hook) {
  global $pager_total;
  $variables['tags'][4] = $pager_total[0];
}
```

I added a conditional so the last pager item wouldn't appear twice on the last couple pages:

```
function hook_preprocess_pager(&$variables, $hook) {
  global $pager_total;
  $variables['tags'][4] = $pager_total[0];
  if( is_numeric( $_GET['page'] ) &&  $pager_total[0] - 6 < $_GET['page'] ) $variables['tags'][4] = '';
}
```

I set the first page to "1" in the view settings, then use a similar conditional so it doesn't appear twice on the first couple pages.

```
function hook_preprocess_pager(&$variables, $hook) {
  global $pager_total;
  $variables['tags'][4] = $pager_total[0];
  if( is_numeric( $_GET['page'] ) &&  $pager_total[0] - 6 < $_GET['page'] ) $variables['tags'][4] = '';
  if( is_numeric( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] < 5 ) $variables['tags'][0] = '';
}
```

This seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

For the next and previous links, you can use CSS Flexbox order property to move them on start and end position :

```
.pager {
  .pager__items {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    .pager__item {
      &.pager__item--previous {
        order: -1;
      }

      &.pager__item--next {
        order: 10;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can implement hook_preprocess_pager() to set first and last text number :

```
function hook_preprocess_pager(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['pager']['#element'];

  /* @var $pager_manager \Drupal\Core\Pager\PagerManagerInterface */
  $pager_manager = \Drupal::service('pager.manager');
  $pager = $pager_manager->getPager($element);

  // Nothing to do if there is no pager.
  if (!isset($pager)) {
    return;
  }
  $pager_max = $pager->getTotalPages();

  // Nothing to do if there is only one page.
  if ($pager_max <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  $tags = $variables['pager']['#tags'];

  // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
  // Middle is used to "center" pages around the current page.
  $current_page = $pager->getCurrentPage();

  // Alter the "first" link.
  if (isset($tags[0]) && $current_page > 1) {
    $variables['items']['first']['text'] = 1;
  }
  else {
    unset($variables['items']['first']);
  }

  // Alter the "last" link.
  if (isset($tags[4]) && $current_page < ($pager_max - 2)) {
    $variables['items']['last']['text'] = $pager_max;
  }
  else {
    unset($variables['items']['last']);
  }
}
```